# Accessing value in PHP SoapClient response element with attribute

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a problem with processing a PHP `SoapClient` response...

I know that I can access response XML elements using object notation:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
$data=$client->Method(array('Param'=>"Value"));
$tmp = $data->Results->Asset->Attributes>Attribute;
var_dump($tmp);
```

The problem is when I am trying to reach element with some attribute...
Here is part of the XML resposne:

```
<Results>
 <Asset>
  <Attributes>
   <Attribute Name="ID">0</Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="FirstName">John</Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Size">Large</Attribute>
  </Attributes>
 </Asset>
 <Asset>
  <Attributes>
   <Attribute Name="ID">1</Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="FirstName">Bob</Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Size">Medium</Attribute>
  </Attributes>
 </Asset>
 <Asset>
  <Attributes>
   <Attribute Name="ID">2</Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="FirstName">Frank</Attribute>
   <Attribute Name="Size">Small</Attribute>
  </Attributes>
 </Asset>
</Results>
```

How to get value from element "Attribute" with attribute "Size" using object notation?
In `print_r` I am getting an array with `stdClass` inside (it is only a part of it)

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Attribute] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => 0
                        [Name] => ID
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => John
                        [Name] => FirstName
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => Large
                        [Name] => Size
                    )
            )
        )
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Attribute] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => 1
                        [Name] => ID
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => Bob
                        [Name] => FirstName
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => Medium
                        [Name] => Size
                    )
            )
        )
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Attribute] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => 2
                        [Name] => ID
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => Frank
                        [Name] => FirstName
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_] => Small
                        [Name] => Size
                    )
            )
        )
    )
```

I know that i can probably use

```
$client->__getLastResponse()
```

and parse with `SimpleXMLElement` but it does not seem optimal for me...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it at `$data->Results->Asset->Attributes->Attribute[0]->_`.

If you want to search for your value where the attribute is "size" then you will probably need a loop. It's hard to tell what your data looks like with such a small sample, but I don't believe more concise methods like `array_column()` will work with that structure.

```
<?php
foreach ($data->Results->Asset as $Asset) {
    foreach ($Asset->Attributes->Attribute as $Attribute) {
        if ($Attribute->Name === "Size") {
            echo $Attribute->_;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for Your answer and corrections! TBH I know that I Can use foreach and point index in array. I was looking for more fancy solution like in SimpleXML: $simplexml->xpath('/Results/Asset/Attributes/Attribute[@Name="size"]'); Why the part of response from SoapClient is an incremental index with class as an element and not something similar to xPath? In that case looking for specific attribute with foreach does not seem as an optimal solution for me... Is there any way to format SoapClient response structure to make it more like xpath example?

Comment: If you want to use XPath, then you need to load the XML into DomDocument or SimpleXML. Your question said you didn't want to do this.

Comment: I am not saying that I want to avoid loading __getLastResponse() to SimpleXML at all costs. I just have some efficiency concerns... Since I already have response as an object, I am trying to find a method to use it in a way I need. Making second object from pure xml response, just looks inefficient for me... But maybe I am wrong...

Comment: I have already made an alternative solution based on __getLastResponse() and SimpleXML but I had dealt with removing colons from soap:Envelope & soap:Body and using preg_replace to make it usable to SimpleXML and then removing namespaces from XML (problem with registering default namespace for xPath) to able to select xpath("Attribute [@Name=\"Size\"]") - in brief: it works but it is ugly...

Comment: Now I am looking back at SoapClient native response and that what You said about simply selecting array index: $data->Results->Asset->Attributes->Attribute[0]->_. In my case if I am willing to get size I should select index number 2 instead of 0 since there is order correlation. Now my question. How to protect against xml response elements order changes in that case?

Comment: You're searching for a particular name, it doesn't matter what index it's at. See my final edits based on your updated question.