# assigning SOAP value to a variable

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to extract, for example, ServiceType from this SOAP call. In the below example, it is showing FTTN

```
if (VocusDevController::login()) {

            $client = new SoapClient('wsdl/VocusSchemas/WholesaleServiceManagement.wsdl', array(
                'trace' => 1,
                'exception' => true
            ));
        
            try {
        
                $response = $client->Get(array(
                    "AccessKey" => "SOMEKEY", 
                    "ProductID" => "FIBRE",
                    "Scope" => "QUALIFY",
                    "Parameters" => array('Param' => array('_' => 'LOC000023125730', 'id' => 'DirectoryID'))
                ));

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($response);
                echo '</pre>';
                echo '<hr>';
                // $output = $response->Parameters->Param->ServiceType; // This is where I am trying to extract ServiceType
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                echo 'Exception Thrown: ' . $exception->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

This is the output I get from the above call

```
stdClass Object
(
    [TransactionID] => 17A935CDC7E1906
    [ResponseType] => SYNC
    [Parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Param] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => PASS
                            [id] => Result
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => FTTN
                            [id] => ServiceType
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => 13
                            [id] => ServiceClass
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => Type 1
                            [id] => ConnectionType
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => 20210910
                            [id] => CopperDisconnectionDate
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => Urban
                            [id] => Zone
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => FALSE
                            [id] => DevelopmentCharge
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => CSA200000000332
                            [id] => CSA
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => Auto-Assigned
                            [id] => CVCID
                        )

                    [9] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => CPI300009724591N/ALine In Use13N/AFALSE5Mbps,10Mbps,20Mbps33-3577-82TRUEFALSE
                            [id] => CopperPairRecord
                        )

                    [10] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_] => LOC000023125730NBNLOT: 18 1 CHILDS CCT BELROSE NSW
                            [id] => BroadbandAddressRecord
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to extract ServiceType with `$output = $response->Parameters->Param->ServiceType;`, However, I just get this error:-

```
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "ServiceType" on array
```

So, I am obviously trying to extract it incorrectly. Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @miken32 's respose here [Accessing value in PHP SoapClient response element with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002477/accessing-value-in-php-soapclient-response-element-with-attribute)
I have used the following to pull ServiceType succesfully.

```
        $data = $response->Parameters->Param[1]->_;
        dd($data);
```